# MySQL: How to avoid a user from even seeing I have other DB's and grant select access to one view on one DB?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

I have several DB's in my server, and I need to allow one user to select records from a view in one of the DB's. But I need for this user to not even see that there are other DB's nor see that there are other tables in the DB where the view belongs. Is this possible?

I had an account with a hosting company, a shared hosting account, and I could only see my DB when I accessed it through phpmyadmin. This is similar to what I need. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the overview contained in [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm) even more helpful than the actual [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html) for describing the big picture of how MySQL privileges are granted or denied.

The gist of the overview article is that privileges are controlled by a series of increasingly finer-grained permissions tables in the `mysql` database: `mysql.user`, `mysql.db`, `mysql.host`, `mysql.tables_priv`, `mysql.columns_priv`, `mysql.procs_priv`.  The general rule is that a "Y" value for a privilege in a more fine-grained table overrules a "N" value in a more coarse-grained table.  So the recommended strategy is to start by denying most privileges in the `user` table (which gives the coarsest control), and then make only the specific overrides that you want in the more fine-grained tables.

In particular, there is a privilege called [SHOW_DATABASES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases) which is determined by the `Show_db_priv` column in the `mysql.user` table; you'll want to set this to "N" for the user in question (and as described above, you may want to set most other permissions in the user table to "N" as well) and then grant only the privileges that the user actually needs in the `mysql.db` or `mysql.tables_priv` table or whatever would be appropriate for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a user to a database using grant privileges.

Create new databases and simply **don't** add the user to it then the user won't be able to see it.

The only way the user will be able to find the database is if they try to access it and guess the database name. So basically a user/hacker would have to attempt to connect to a bunch of random database names in order to find one that says "access denied"