# how to make a user to avoid accessing one database assigned than other databases in the server

Tags: php, mysql

as in the title, actually am trying to make some restrictions for the users. like if one user is logged into the local database("am using xampp server") rather than root, and the privileges set as that he can work on only one data base, 
now I want to make the user to avoid checking the data of other databases.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbtest`.* TO 'user_one'@'localhost'WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: You just did that, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, the command you mentioned, does the same.

Comment: thnx,..... yes, its almost done but still the user can see the other databases in the list and also the tables, it mean he can check the data from the tables which have some confidential information,... if any other more secure way is there please help me, cause am new to this technology,.. thnx again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821289/mysql-how-to-avoid-a-user-from-even-seeing-i-have-other-dbs-and-grant-select-a              this question is quit same as my question,..

Comment: Use code blocks for your code! It improves readability.

Comment: ohhh,.. yeah i got it,... when adding the user, then we are not suppose to check any global privileges,.. its worked,.. thnx for your support,... :) –